# I dont have wireless internet

Tags: 11.10, wireless, vmware

Im using Ubuntu 11.10 on windows 7 with the VMware program.
My laptop is Toshiba Satellite P505-S8980 and I connected to the internet with Wifi.
whem I'm using my windows 7 I have WiFi networks, but when I open Ubuntu (on the VMware)
I have only wired connection available (which is weird becaouse I don't have any internet wire connected to the computer) and no wireless connection (and I need that for something)
my network adapter is: realtek TRL8191SE wireless LAN 802.11n PCI-E.

[image]

(as you can see the "Liverant" network is connected and I can use it with my windows 7)
any help? I tried a lot of things and still nothing helped me.

Answer (score 2):

The connection inside VMware is not hardware related, it is bridged to your hosts connections. It is a virtual adapter, it does not really exist.

When Ubuntu tries to connect to the Internet using that fake adapter VMware will direct that to your real adapter inside Windows.

It is all done by software, even if you remove the adapter inside Ubuntu you Internet will still work in your Windows (the other way around is not true since the virtual adapter will not find any adapter to re-direct the information to, if you disconnect your host Internet connection your guest systems will not have access to the Internet).

This is a crude image of how it works.

[image]

Comment: Short: If you need to direct access to your wireless card, let's say for breaking into some poor soul wireless protected by WEP encryption ;), you can't do it from a Virtual Machine. You will need a real install.

Comment: Well VirtualBox allow that the guest has a lock on a USB device. That enables you to share directly the hardware installed on Windows with your Ubuntu guest, use a USB wireless adapter and you have have your cake and eat it.

Comment: so what you guys saying is that I can't have a wireless connection with a virtual machine but if I installed Ubunto as my real operating system it would work?

Comment: Yeah, thats the idea. Like said, on some situations you can share some hardware directly to your guest (Ubuntu in your case) from your host (Windows in your case) but normally not, it is done via virtual adapters and bridges.

Comment: You can't access *directly* to the wireless card (unless it is an usb device as Bruno commented). You should be able to browse internet just fine, most normal things should work with the emulated wired connection (but no things that done dirty things to hardware like wireless cracking).

Answer (score 0):

With VMware you create a virtual computer (usually with different hardware). The wired connection is a connection between the virtual computer (running Ubuntu) and your real computer (running Windows 7). This wired connection is attached to VMnet1 or VMnet8 as you can see in your screen shot. Your real computer is connected wireless to the internet but it's providing the internet connection to Ubuntu through a virtual wired connection.

Comment: so what you guys saying is that I can't have a wireless connection with a virtual machine but if I installed Ubunto as my real operating system it would work?